# Ratio of lines intersecting in a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

In $ABC$ triangle $M$ is the mid point of $BC$ and $N$ is a point on $AB$ that such that  $AN:NB = 2:1$. $AM$ and $CN$ are intersected at the point $D$. What is the ratio of $AD:DM$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By way of mass points we get the ratio is 4:1.

Place a weight 1 on B and C. Then the weight on M is 2. Since AN:NB is 2:1, and B has weight 1, A has a weight .5. Now M has weight 2 and A has weight .5 so the ratio of AD:DM is 2: .5 = 4:1.

Comment: This answer gave me a new way to think. Its a great way to react in such questions. What we have to do is assuming the lines as rods and points on rods as fulcrums the rods are placed. Now it will become a simple physics problem.

Comment: Yes it is. Its a nifty way to solve geometry problems, especially for high school math competitions.

Answer (score 0):

$$area(\triangle DMC):area(\triangle BCD) =MC:BC=1:2$$
and $$area(\triangle BCD):area(\triangle ACD) = BN:AN=1:2.$$
So 
$$DM:AD = area(\triangle DMC):area(\triangle ACD) = 1:4.$$

Comment: $area(\triangle DMC):area(\triangle BCD) =MC:BC$ 
How this happens?

Can anyone briefly explain the theory behind this above relationships?

Comment: The two triangles share the same altitude from $D$ to $BC$.

Comment: The answer seems like great. But I did not understand it yet.